# Finding the appropriate distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I'm trying to solve this problem I put to myself (it's not actually homework) but it can be considered a simple physics problem.

I want to design a mechanism that allows me to open a gate a given angle by pushing it with a rod that can only be moved up and down.

The scheme of the problem I draw is as follows:
[image: Scheme of the problem]

Rod A is to be opened till aligning its axis with the dashed line forming 70º with respect to the initial gate position. Rod B is to push the gate as it moves up, sliding on the slot C (fixed). **I want to know the height that slot C needs to have in order to open the gate 70º when the top is reached.**

I have tried different trigonometric relationships and I have not obtained any solution.

I need a hint to get the solution of the problem, I suppose it has to be solved by using trigonometry. Otherwise, I'm really stuck. Don't look at the measures.

**Observation**: I'm only asking for some kind of hint on how to start, because after multiple attempts I have not been able to obtain a solution.

EDIT: While trying to solve it, I also thought of the following question: "Must the slot upper limit must be at the same height as the 70º axis in order to open the gate until that point?"

Comment: You need to define the horizontal distance between the axis of rotation of the gate and the tip of rod B, and the distance between the top of slot C and the horizontal line from the axis of the gate. Once you have those, draw triangles for the "open" and "close" gate - the trig should then be easy. Since you only asked for a hint, see how far that gets you.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but when you say "the distance between the top of slot C and the horizontal line from the axis of the gate", how can I define this distance if I don't know the height of the slot and the gate is initially tilted approximately 20 degrees? I mean this distance will vary depending on the "height" I'm trying to solve.

Comment: You drew the gate in the "open" (70 deg) position. Do you expect it to be able to be closed all the way? Try drawing the full range of motion and the position of the bar in both cases. Doesn't the height of the slots then follow?

Comment: Good! You might want to draw your solution as an "answer" - that way other people with the same problem would be able to find their solution...